# Whether string has English language characters - a code in Python

Tags: python, string

Please review why the two pieces of code would produce different        results. The goal is to return True or False if the input string has any character that is NOT in English language.

Code 1:

```
def char_find(string):
    for char in string:
        if (ord(char) >= 0) and ord(char) <= 127:
            return True
        else:
            return False

result1 = char_find('爱奇艺PPS -《欢乐颂2》电视剧热播')
result2 = char_find('Docs To Go™ Free Office Suite')
result3 = char_find('Instachat ')
print(result1, result2, result3)
```

This produces the result False, True, True

Code 2:

```
def is_english(string):
    for char in string:
        if ord(char) > 127:
            return False
    return True

resultX = is_english('爱奇艺PPS -《欢乐颂2》电视剧热播')
resultY = is_english('Docs To Go™ Free Office Suite')
resultZ = is_english('Instachat ')
print(resultX, resultY, resultZ)
```

This produces the result False, False, False

I don't understand why the first piece of code yields incorrect results.

Comment: The first piece only looks at the first character of the string.

Comment: Returning `True` exits the for loop on the first iteration

Answer (score 1):

In code 1, you return `True` if you find an English character else a `False` but in code 2, you return a `False` if you find a non-English character. Only if all characters are English does this return a `True`.

The key point to note is you exit from the function with the value passed along with `return` once you encounter a `return`.

You can do this more pythonically using `string` module and `all` on a generator:

```
def is_english(s):
    return all(char.lower() in string.ascii_lowercase for char in s)
```

which will return a `True` if all are English characters else a `False`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first function, you iterate over all characters with `for char in string`, but since both cases of the if statement have an explicit return, you never check any character after the first one.

Thats why it returns `False, True, True`, since the first characters are 爱, D, I.

Answer (score 0):

When you're in a function, the `return` keyword means "stop whatever you're doing, take this value, and return it to whoever asked for it." So, your first function starts looping through every single character in the string.

It starts with the first character, and checks if its Unicode representation is between 0 and 127. If it is, it **returns True to** `result1`. That's it. The function is now done, and Python proceeds to the next line of code, which is checking `result2`.

The same happens if if it's not between 0 and 127, the code returns False and then stops.

Either way, once you hit a `return` statement, your function is over. Since your first string starts with a non-English character, it returns false. Since your second two strings start with English characters, they return true.

Answer (score 0):

In code 1, 
Even though you have loop, you have if else statement inside it and both if and else contains return statement. So it always checks the first character and return the result.

This is why it returns `False, True, True`, because it checks only the first characters i.e 爱, D, I

While in code 2,
You iterate through the characters, inside the loop you return value only if you find non English character. So it will check all the characters and if the string doesn't contain any non English characters, the loop will complete the iteration and `True` will be returned as you put return statement after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Create a test function that effectively does the work of both functions and compare the results yourself:

```
def char_find(string):
    for char in string:
        if ord(char) > 127:
            print(char, '=>', ord(char))
            print('you would return false here')
        if (ord(char) >= 0) and ord(char) <= 127:
            print(char, '=>', ord(char))
            print('you would return true here')

 char_find('爱奇艺PPS -《欢乐颂2》电视剧热播')
```

output:

```
爱 => 29233
you would return false here
奇 => 22855
you would return false here
艺 => 33402
you would return false here
P => 80
you would return true here
P => 80
you would return true here
S => 83
you would return true here
  => 32
you would return true here
- => 45
you would return true here
《 => 12298
you would return false here
欢 => 27426
you would return false here
乐 => 20048
you would return false here
颂 => 39042
you would return false here
2 => 50
you would return true here
》 => 12299
you would return false here
电 => 30005
you would return false here
视 => 35270
you would return false here
剧 => 21095
you would return false here
热 => 28909
you would return false here
播 => 25773
you would return false here
```